# ADT bundle xml issue

Tags: android, eclipse, background

im trying to build an application using the android developer tools bundle, and im getting a weird graphical view in one of my XML files. I just opened up one of my XML files and the palette background and the preview background have both turned black all of a sudden. Its not anything to do with a Background color or theme that i set because all my other XML files are white and also when i run the affected page in my Emulator its showing a white background as well.

I have also tried completely different layouts and clearing the XML code entirely to default , but its still black.

I tried to add in a picture but i haven't got enough reputation points , but i hope someone know what im talking about as its quite hard to explain.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating another project and use android 2.2 to build with.